# CSS Highlight Child Elements - Rating System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so inside my div, when you hover over the 4th image, the first 3 and the fourth one will get the css property opacity and have its value as 1.

I'm not sure exactly how I would do this, I read a bit about nth-child, but thats not helping me with hovering. Also if you click on the 4th image would it be possible to make all 4 except the last one stay at opacity 1.

```
 <div class="rating" style="width:75px;">
    <span>
        <img class="plus" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Chip-1-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <img class="plus" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Chip-1-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />\
    </span>
    <span>
        <img class="plus" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Chip-1-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <img class="plus" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Chip-1-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <img class="plus" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Chip-1-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />
    </span>
</div>
```

If you don't understand and need me to say it more clearly or if you need more information just let me know!

CSS:

```
.rating span img {
    opacity:0.5;
}

.rating:hover span img {
    opacity:1;
}

.rating:hover span:hover ~ span img {
    opacity:0.5
}
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.plus {
    opacity:0.5;
}
.plus:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
  padding:1px;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: `opacity:1` means completely opaque. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can go backwards one element using the ~ but you cant traverse back entire sibling elements. OHHH HOW I WISH!!!

Comment: Yes, @Jivings they're by default 0.5 until you hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure css way of doing this:

CSS

```
.rating span img {
    opacity:0.5;
}

.rating:hover span img {
    opacity:1;
}

.rating:hover span:hover ~ span img {
    opacity:0.5
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ac2m3/)

Comment: Hey, it works! Although it seems to go from the last element to the first, rather than first to last.

Comment: ah i see what you mean

Comment: No that is the way its supposed to be but when I add that CSS, it'll make it so when you select the first element it'll highlight all 5, and when you select the last element it'll only select that one. Almost like it is in reverse. I don't believe its this code, I believe its because my first span is placed at the back rather than the front. How would I fix this? I'll post my CSS code

Comment: Yea its the rtl direction style that is making them go in reverse. Ill have to look at the code further to see if there is a css way to reverse it while keeping the rtl

Comment: @user3023566 Good. What did you change so that others that come by this know?

Comment: I deleted direction:rtl.

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [**:lt()**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.plus').hover(function () {
        $('img.plus:lt(' + $(this).index() + ')').css('opacity', 1);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mR4Z3/2/)

[**DEMO with current element also**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mR4Z3/4/)

Comment: I understand how the code would work here, but I put that in the head and it didn't affect anything, no errors in console.

Comment: This would make all of the images with class `plus` have a hover event, when it seems like they only want the 4th image to have the hover event.

Comment: No, I actually forgot *facepalm* I feel stupid. Although I did now and its still not working :/ And no nate, it is the fourth image and the first 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use this jQuery function:

```
// Highlight selected stars
$(document).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", 'span', function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().toggleClass('highlight');

});
```

When you hover an icon all the icons before and it self, will toggle their class'

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mR4Z3/3/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'